# Cleanup interrupted apt installation

Tags: drivers, apt, nvidia

In an attempt to install the NVIDIA driver on my Ubuntu Server 16.04.5 for a Quadro 2000 GF106GL, I followed the recommended procedure from ubuntuusers and ran

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-drivers-common
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

To my utter horror, this immediately started `apt-get` and without further request proceeded to install to whole freaking GNOME desktop on my nice clean system that only uses basic XFCE - I had to do Control+D:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  apg aptdaemon avahi-utils bbswitch-dkms bluez bluez-obexd cheese-common cracklib-runtime
  cups-pk-helper dconf-cli diffstat dkms evolution-data-server evolution-data-server-common
  evolution-data-server-online-accounts gcr geoclue geoclue-ubuntu-geoip gir1.2-gnomekeyring-1.0
  gir1.2-ibus-1.0 gir1.2-notify-0.7 gir1.2-packagekitglib-1.0 gkbd-capplet gnome-bluetooth
  gnome-desktop3-data gnome-keyring gnome-menus gnome-power-manager gnome-screensaver
  gnome-session-bin gnome-settings-daemon-schemas gnome-user-guide gnome-user-share
  gsettings-ubuntu-schemas gstreamer1.0-clutter-3.0 gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gstreamer1.0-x
  gvfs-backends hardening-includes hwdata ibus im-config indicator-applet indicator-application
  indicator-bluetooth indicator-datetime indicator-keyboard indicator-messages indicator-power
  indicator-session indicator-sound ippusbxd iputils-arping libaa1 libaccount-plugin-1.0-0
  libaccount-plugin-generic-oauth libaccount-plugin-google libaccounts-glib0 libaccounts-qt5-1
  libappindicator3-1 libapt-pkg-perl libassuan0 libavc1394-0 libcamel-1.2-54 libcanberra-pulse
  libcdio-cdda1 libcdio-paranoia1 libcdio13 libcgi-fast-perl libcgi-pm-perl libcheese-gtk25 libcheese8
  libclass-accessor-perl libclone-perl libclutter-1.0-0 libclutter-1.0-common libclutter-gst-3.0-0
  libclutter-gtk-1.0-0 libcogl-common libcogl-pango20 libcogl-path20 libcogl20 libcrack2 libcuda1-384
  libdata-alias-perl libdigest-hmac-perl libdouble-conversion1v5 libdv4 libebackend-1.2-10
  libebook-1.2-16 libebook-contacts-1.2-2 libecal-1.2-19 libedata-book-1.2-25 libedata-cal-1.2-28
  libedataserver-1.2-21 libemail-valid-perl libexporter-tiny-perl libfcgi-perl libfcitx-config4
  libfcitx-gclient0 libfcitx-utils0 libfile-basedir-perl libgcr-ui-3-1 libgdata-common libgdata22
  libgee-0.8-2 libgeoclue0 libgeocode-glib0 libgeonames0 libgnome-bluetooth13 libgnome-desktop-3-12
  libgnome-menu-3-0 libgnomekbd-common libgnomekbd8 libgoa-1.0-0b libgoa-1.0-common
  libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0 libgtop-2.0-10 libgtop2-common libgweather-3-6 libgweather-common
  libharfbuzz-icu0 libhyphen0 libibus-1.0-5 libido3-0.1-0 libiec61883-0 libindicator3-7 libio-pty-perl
  libio-socket-inet6-perl libio-string-perl libipc-run-perl libipc-system-simple-perl libjansson4
  libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18 liblightdm-gobject-1-0 liblist-moreutils-perl libmbim-glib4
  libmbim-proxy libmm-glib0 libmtp-common libmtp-runtime libmtp9 libndp0 libnet-dns-perl
  libnet-domain-tld-perl libnet-ip-perl libnm-glib4 libnm-gtk-common libnm-gtk0 libnm-util2 libnm0
  libnma-common libnma0 liboauth0 libp11-kit-gnome-keyring libpackagekit-glib2-16 libpam-gnome-keyring
  libpanel-applet0 libparse-debianchangelog-perl libperlio-gzip-perl libpwquality-common libpwquality1
  libqmi-glib5 libqmi-proxy libqt5opengl5 libqt5qml5 libqt5quick5 libqt5webkit5 libraw1394-11
  libshout3 libsignon-extension1 libsignon-glib1 libsignon-plugins-common1 libsignon-qt5-1
  libsmbclient libsocket6-perl libsub-name-perl libtag1v5 libtag1v5-vanilla libtext-levenshtein-perl
  libtimezonemap-data libtimezonemap1 libunity-control-center1 libunity-settings-daemon1
  liburl-dispatcher1 libv4l-0 libv4lconvert0 libvdpau1 libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37-gtk2
  libwebpdemux1 libxnvctrl0 libyaml-libyaml-perl libyelp0 lightdm lintian mesa-vdpau-drivers
  mobile-broadband-provider-info modemmanager mountall mousetweaks nautilus-data network-manager
  network-manager-gnome network-manager-pptp nvidia-opencl-icd-384 nvidia-prime nvidia-settings
  ocl-icd-libopencl1 p11-kit p11-kit-modules patchutils pinentry-gnome3 pkg-config policykit-1-gnome
  ppp pptp-linux python3-aptdaemon python3-aptdaemon.pkcompat python3-bs4 python3-cairo python3-cups
  python3-cupshelpers python3-defer python3-html5lib python3-lxml python3-xdg screen-resolution-extra
  session-migration signon-keyring-extension signon-plugin-oauth2 signon-plugin-password signon-ui
  signon-ui-service signon-ui-x11 signond system-config-printer-common system-config-printer-gnome
  system-config-printer-udev t1utils ubuntu-system-service ubuntu-touch-sounds unity-control-center
  unity-control-center-faces unity-control-center-signon unity-greeter unity-settings-daemon upstart
  usb-modeswitch usb-modeswitch-data vdpau-driver-all wpasupplicant xserver-xorg-legacy yelp yelp-xsl
Suggested packages: [stripped due to askubuntu character limit]
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apg aptdaemon avahi-utils bbswitch-dkms bluez bluez-obexd cheese-common cracklib-runtime
  cups-pk-helper dconf-cli diffstat dkms evolution-data-server evolution-data-server-common
  evolution-data-server-online-accounts gcr geoclue geoclue-ubuntu-geoip gir1.2-gnomekeyring-1.0
  gir1.2-ibus-1.0 gir1.2-notify-0.7 gir1.2-packagekitglib-1.0 gkbd-capplet gnome-bluetooth
  gnome-desktop3-data gnome-keyring gnome-menus gnome-power-manager gnome-screensaver
  gnome-session-bin gnome-settings-daemon-schemas gnome-user-guide gnome-user-share
  gsettings-ubuntu-schemas gstreamer1.0-clutter-3.0 gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gstreamer1.0-x
  gvfs-backends hardening-includes hwdata ibus im-config indicator-applet indicator-application
  indicator-bluetooth indicator-datetime indicator-keyboard indicator-messages indicator-power
  indicator-session indicator-sound ippusbxd iputils-arping libaa1 libaccount-plugin-1.0-0
  libaccount-plugin-generic-oauth libaccount-plugin-google libaccounts-glib0 libaccounts-qt5-1
  libappindicator3-1 libapt-pkg-perl libassuan0 libavc1394-0 libcamel-1.2-54 libcanberra-pulse
  libcdio-cdda1 libcdio-paranoia1 libcdio13 libcgi-fast-perl libcgi-pm-perl libcheese-gtk25 libcheese8
  libclass-accessor-perl libclone-perl libclutter-1.0-0 libclutter-1.0-common libclutter-gst-3.0-0
  libclutter-gtk-1.0-0 libcogl-common libcogl-pango20 libcogl-path20 libcogl20 libcrack2 libcuda1-384
  libdata-alias-perl libdigest-hmac-perl libdouble-conversion1v5 libdv4 libebackend-1.2-10
  libebook-1.2-16 libebook-contacts-1.2-2 libecal-1.2-19 libedata-book-1.2-25 libedata-cal-1.2-28
  libedataserver-1.2-21 libemail-valid-perl libexporter-tiny-perl libfcgi-perl libfcitx-config4
  libfcitx-gclient0 libfcitx-utils0 libfile-basedir-perl libgcr-ui-3-1 libgdata-common libgdata22
  libgee-0.8-2 libgeoclue0 libgeocode-glib0 libgeonames0 libgnome-bluetooth13 libgnome-desktop-3-12
  libgnome-menu-3-0 libgnomekbd-common libgnomekbd8 libgoa-1.0-0b libgoa-1.0-common
  libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0 libgtop-2.0-10 libgtop2-common libgweather-3-6 libgweather-common
  libharfbuzz-icu0 libhyphen0 libibus-1.0-5 libido3-0.1-0 libiec61883-0 libindicator3-7 libio-pty-perl
  libio-socket-inet6-perl libio-string-perl libipc-run-perl libipc-system-simple-perl libjansson4
  libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18 liblightdm-gobject-1-0 liblist-moreutils-perl libmbim-glib4
  libmbim-proxy libmm-glib0 libmtp-common libmtp-runtime libmtp9 libndp0 libnet-dns-perl
  libnet-domain-tld-perl libnet-ip-perl libnm-glib4 libnm-gtk-common libnm-gtk0 libnm-util2 libnm0
  libnma-common libnma0 liboauth0 libp11-kit-gnome-keyring libpackagekit-glib2-16 libpam-gnome-keyring
  libpanel-applet0 libparse-debianchangelog-perl libperlio-gzip-perl libpwquality-common libpwquality1
  libqmi-glib5 libqmi-proxy libqt5opengl5 libqt5qml5 libqt5quick5 libqt5webkit5 libraw1394-11
  libshout3 libsignon-extension1 libsignon-glib1 libsignon-plugins-common1 libsignon-qt5-1
  libsmbclient libsocket6-perl libsub-name-perl libtag1v5 libtag1v5-vanilla libtext-levenshtein-perl
  libtimezonemap-data libtimezonemap1 libunity-control-center1 libunity-settings-daemon1
  liburl-dispatcher1 libv4l-0 libv4lconvert0 libvdpau1 libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37-gtk2
  libwebpdemux1 libxnvctrl0 libyaml-libyaml-perl libyelp0 lightdm lintian mesa-vdpau-drivers
  mobile-broadband-provider-info modemmanager mountall mousetweaks nautilus-data network-manager
  network-manager-gnome network-manager-pptp nvidia-384 nvidia-opencl-icd-384 nvidia-prime
  nvidia-settings ocl-icd-libopencl1 p11-kit p11-kit-modules patchutils pinentry-gnome3 pkg-config
  policykit-1-gnome ppp pptp-linux python3-aptdaemon python3-aptdaemon.pkcompat python3-bs4
  python3-cairo python3-cups python3-cupshelpers python3-defer python3-html5lib python3-lxml
  python3-xdg screen-resolution-extra session-migration signon-keyring-extension signon-plugin-oauth2
  signon-plugin-password signon-ui signon-ui-service signon-ui-x11 signond
  system-config-printer-common system-config-printer-gnome system-config-printer-udev t1utils
  ubuntu-system-service ubuntu-touch-sounds unity-control-center unity-control-center-faces
  unity-control-center-signon unity-greeter unity-settings-daemon upstart usb-modeswitch
  usb-modeswitch-data vdpau-driver-all wpasupplicant xserver-xorg-legacy yelp yelp-xsl
0 upgraded, 256 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 163 MB of archives.
After this operation, 731 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 libgcr-ui-3-1 amd64 3.18.0-1ubuntu1 [141 kB]

Fetched 163 MB in 4s (35.3 MB/s)             
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgcr-ui-3-1:amd64.
(Reading database ... 160381 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libgcr-ui-3-1_3.18.0-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgcr-ui-3-1:amd64 (3.18.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package gcr.
Preparing to unpack .../gcr_3.18.0-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gcr (3.18.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package p11-kit-modules:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../p11-kit-modules_0.23.2-5~ubuntu16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking p11-kit-modules:amd64 (0.23.2-5~ubuntu16.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package p11-kit.
Preparing to unpack .../p11-kit_0.23.2-5~ubuntu16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking p11-kit (0.23.2-5~ubuntu16.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libassuan0:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libassuan0_2.4.2-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libassuan0:amd64 (2.4.2-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package pinentry-gnome3.
Preparing to unpack .../pinentry-gnome3_0.9.7-3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking pinentry-gnome3 (0.9.7-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package gnome-keyring.
Preparing to unpack .../gnome-keyring_3.18.3-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gnome-keyring (3.18.3-0ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libindicator3-7.
Preparing to unpack .../libindicator3-7_12.10.2+16.04.20151208-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libindicator3-7 (12.10.2+16.04.20151208-0ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libappindicator3-1.
Preparing to unpack .../libappindicator3-1_12.10.1+16.04.20170215-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libappindicator3-1 (12.10.1+16.04.20170215-0ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgeoclue0:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libgeoclue0_0.12.99-4ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgeoclue0:amd64 (0.12.99-4ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libraw1394-11:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libraw1394-11_2.1.1-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libraw1394-11:amd64 (2.1.1-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libiec61883-0:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libiec61883-0_1.2.0-0.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libiec61883-0:amd64 (1.2.0-0.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libmtp-common.
Preparing to unpack .../libmtp-common_1.1.10-2ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libmtp-common (1.1.10-2ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libmtp9:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libmtp9_1.1.10-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libmtp9:amd64 (1.1.10-2ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libp11-kit-gnome-keyring:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libp11-kit-gnome-keyring_3.18.3-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libp11-kit-gnome-keyring:amd64 (3.18.3-0ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libpam-gnome-keyring:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libpam-gnome-keyring_3.18.3-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpam-gnome-keyring:amd64 (3.18.3-0ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libqt5opengl5:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libqt5opengl5_5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.5_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libqt5opengl5:amd64 (5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.5) ...
driverTraceback (most recent call last):
                                          File "/usr/bin/ubuntu-drivers", line 170, in <module>
                                                                                                   sys.exit(command(args))
                    File "/usr/bin/ubuntu-drivers", line 101, in command_autoinstall
                                                                                        'DPkg::options::=--force-confnew', '-y'] + to_install)
                                        File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 559, in call
                                                                                                      return p.wait(timeout=timeout)
                              File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1658, in wait
                                                                                             (pid, sts) = self._try_wait(0)
                     File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1608, in _try_wait
                                                                                         (pid, sts) = os.waitpid(self.pid, wait_flags)
                              KeyboardInterrupt
```

How can I recover safely to the point before starting `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`?

Edit: Here are the last lines of the requested logfile:

```
Start-Date: 2018-08-14  14:39:30
Commandline: apt-get install -o DPkg::options::=--force-confnew -y nvidia-384
Requested-By: noob (1000)
Install: libunity-settings-daemon1:amd64 (15.04.1+16.04.20160701-0ubuntu1, automatic), gkbd-capplet:amd64 (3.6.0-1ubuntu2, automatic), libnm-glib4:amd64 (1.2.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.2, automatic), libqmi-proxy:amd64 (1.16.2-1ubuntu0.16.04.1, automatic), network-manager-pptp:amd64 (1.1.93-1ubuntu1, automatic), bluez:amd64 (5.37-0ubuntu5.1, automatic), python3-defer:amd64 (1.0.6-2build1, automatic), signon-plugin-password:amd64 (8.58+16.04.20151106-0ubuntu1, automatic), evolution-data-server-common:amd64 (3.18.5-1ubuntu1.1, automatic), gnome-power-manager:amd64 (3.18.0-1ubuntu1, automatic), libgdata-common:amd64 (0.17.4-1, automatic), gnome-keyring:amd64 (3.18.3-0ubuntu2, automatic), python3-html5lib:amd64 (0.999-4, automatic), libcogl20:amd64 (1.22.0-2, automatic), python3-cupshelpers:amd64 (1.5.7+20160212-0ubuntu2, automatic), libdouble-conversion1v5:amd64 (2.0.1-3ubuntu2, automatic), libaa1:amd64 (1.4p5-44build1, automatic), libpackagekit-glib2-16:amd64 (0.8.17-4ubuntu6~gcc5.4ubuntu1.3, automatic), libcrack2:amd64 (2.9.2-1ubuntu1, automatic), mountall:amd64 (2.54ubuntu1, automatic), libraw1394-11:amd64 (2.1.1-2, automatic), gnome-settings-daemon-schemas:amd64 (3.18.2-0ubuntu3.1, automatic), libclutter-1.0-0:amd64 (1.24.2-1, automatic), libgtop2-common:amd64 (2.32.0-1, automatic), unity-control-center-faces:amd64 (15.04.0+16.04.20171130-0ubuntu1, automatic), libclutter-gst-3.0-0:amd64 (3.0.18-1, automatic), mobile-broadband-provider-info:amd64 (20140317-1, automatic), libaccounts-qt5-1:amd64 (1.14+16.04.20151106.1-0ubuntu1, automatic), gvfs-backends:amd64 (1.28.2-1ubuntu1~16.04.2, automatic), libmtp9:amd64 (1.1.10-2ubuntu1, automatic), libfile-basedir-perl:amd64 (0.07-1, automatic), session-migration:amd64 (0.2.3, automatic), gir1.2-notify-0.7:amd64 (0.7.6-2svn1, automatic), liblist-moreutils-perl:amd64 (0.413-1build1, automatic), libparse-debianchangelog-perl:amd64 (1.2.0-8, automatic), libdv4:amd64 (1.0.0-7, automatic), t1utils:amd64 (1.39-2, automatic), libcogl-path20:amd64 (1.22.0-2, automatic), libsignon-qt5-1:amd64 (8.58+16.04.20151106-0ubuntu1, automatic), libgoa-1.0-0b:amd64 (3.18.3-1ubuntu2, automatic), cracklib-runtime:amd64 (2.9.2-1ubuntu1, automatic), libp11-kit-gnome-keyring:amd64 (3.18.3-0ubuntu2, automatic), libgoa-1.0-common:amd64 (3.18.3-1ubuntu2, automatic), libgweather-3-6:amd64 (3.18.2-0ubuntu0.2, automatic), libaccount-plugin-generic-oauth:amd64 (0.12+16.04.20160126-0ubuntu1, automatic), apg:amd64 (2.2.3.dfsg.1-2ubuntu1, automatic), libfcitx-gclient0:amd64 (1:4.2.9.1-1ubuntu1.16.04.2, automatic), libshout3:amd64 (2.3.1-3, automatic), cups-pk-helper:amd64 (0.2.5-2ubuntu2, automatic), libcuda1-384:amd64 (384.130-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, automatic), signon-plugin-oauth2:amd64 (0.23+16.04.20151209-0ubuntu1, automatic), gstreamer1.0-plugins-good:amd64 (1.8.3-1ubuntu0.4, automatic), libipc-system-simple-perl:amd64 (1.25-3, automatic), gsettings-ubuntu-schemas:amd64 (0.0.5+16.04.20160307-0ubuntu1, automatic), libcogl-common:amd64 (1.22.0-2, automatic), libtimezonemap1:amd64 (0.4.5, automatic), gnome-desktop3-data:amd64 (3.18.2-1ubuntu1, automatic), yelp:amd64 (3.18.1-1ubuntu4, automatic), libyelp0:amd64 (3.18.1-1ubuntu4, automatic), ubuntu-system-service:amd64 (0.3, automatic), policykit-1-gnome:amd64 (0.105-2ubuntu2, automatic), libemail-valid-perl:amd64 (1.198-1, automatic), libcdio13:amd64 (0.83-4.2ubuntu1, automatic), signond:amd64 (8.58+16.04.20151106-0ubuntu1, automatic), iputils-arping:amd64 (3:20121221-5ubuntu2, automatic), libsignon-plugins-common1:amd64 (8.58+16.04.20151106-0ubuntu1, automatic), libcgi-fast-perl:amd64 (1:2.10-1, automatic), p11-kit:amd64 (0.23.2-5~ubuntu16.04.1, automatic), libnm-gtk-common:amd64 (1.2.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.4, automatic), libqmi-glib5:amd64 (1.16.2-1ubuntu0.16.04.1, automatic), pptp-linux:amd64 (1.8.0-1, automatic), libexporter-tiny-perl:amd64 (0.042-1, automatic), patchutils:amd64 (0.3.4-1, automatic), libvdpau1:amd64 (1.1.1-3ubuntu1, automatic), libfcgi-perl:amd64 (0.77-1build1, automatic), libcdio-cdda1:amd64 (0.83-4.2ubuntu1, automatic), libgdata22:amd64 (0.17.4-1, automatic), libaccount-plugin-1.0-0:amd64 (0.1.8+16.04.20160201-0ubuntu1, automatic), libcgi-pm-perl:amd64 (4.26-1, automatic), libnet-dns-perl:amd64 (0.81-2build1, automatic), gcr:amd64 (3.18.0-1ubuntu1, automatic), libgnome-bluetooth13:amd64 (3.18.2-1ubuntu2, automatic), xserver-xorg-legacy:amd64 (2:1.18.4-0ubuntu0.7, automatic), indicator-sound:amd64 (12.10.2+16.04.20160406-0ubuntu1, automatic), libtext-levenshtein-perl:amd64 (0.13-1, automatic), libperlio-gzip-perl:amd64 (0.19-1build1, automatic), libcogl-pango20:amd64 (1.22.0-2, automatic), indicator-keyboard:amd64 (0.0.0+16.04.20151125-0ubuntu1, automatic), mousetweaks:amd64 (3.12.0-1ubuntu2, automatic), libharfbuzz-icu0:amd64 (1.0.1-1ubuntu0.1, automatic), libindicator3-7:amd64 (12.10.2+16.04.20151208-0ubuntu1, automatic), libio-socket-inet6-perl:amd64 (2.72-2, automatic), libnm0:amd64 (1.2.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.2, automatic), libpwquality-common:amd64 (1.3.0-0ubuntu1, automatic), evolution-data-server:amd64 (3.18.5-1ubuntu1.1, automatic), libappindicator3-1:amd64 (12.10.1+16.04.20170215-0ubuntu1, automatic), network-manager-gnome:amd64 (1.2.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.4, automatic), ubuntu-touch-sounds:amd64 (15.08, automatic), libhyphen0:amd64 (2.8.8-2ubuntu1, automatic), libassuan0:amd64 (2.4.2-2, automatic), network-manager:amd64 (1.2.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.2, automatic), gnome-bluetooth:amd64 (3.18.2-1ubuntu2, automatic), dkms:amd64 (2.2.0.3-2ubuntu11.5, automatic), vdpau-driver-all:amd64 (1.1.1-3ubuntu1, automatic), p11-kit-modules:amd64 (0.23.2-5~ubuntu16.04.1, automatic), liboauth0:amd64 (1.0.3-0ubuntu2, automatic), nvidia-prime:amd64 (0.8.2, automatic), libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0:amd64 (1.8.3-1ubuntu0.4, automatic), libgcr-ui-3-1:amd64 (3.18.0-1ubuntu1, automatic), python3-cups:amd64 (1.9.73-0ubuntu2, automatic), unity-control-center:amd64 (15.04.0+16.04.20171130-0ubuntu1, automatic), libwebpdemux1:amd64 (0.4.4-1, automatic), libpam-gnome-keyring:amd64 (3.18.3-0ubuntu2, automatic), unity-greeter:amd64 (16.04.2-0ubuntu1, automatic), indicator-session:amd64 (12.10.5+16.04.20160412-0ubuntu1, automatic), libapt-pkg-perl:amd64 (0.1.29build7, automatic), gnome-user-guide:amd64 (3.18.1-1, automatic), libqt5qml5:amd64 (5.5.1-2ubuntu6, automatic), libgeocode-glib0:amd64 (3.18.2-1, automatic), python3-xdg:amd64 (0.25-4, automatic), libfcitx-config4:amd64 (1:4.2.9.1-1ubuntu1.16.04.2, automatic), libndp0:amd64 (1.4-2ubuntu0.16.04.1, automatic), libnm-util2:amd64 (1.2.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.2, automatic), geoclue-ubuntu-geoip:amd64 (1.0.2+14.04.20131125-0ubuntu2, automatic), libcdio-paranoia1:amd64 (0.83-4.2ubuntu1, automatic), libxnvctrl0:amd64 (361.42-0ubuntu1, automatic), libmtp-runtime:amd64 (1.1.10-2ubuntu1, automatic), libebackend-1.2-10:amd64 (3.18.5-1ubuntu1.1, automatic), ppp:amd64 (2.4.7-1+2ubuntu1, automatic), libgnome-desktop-3-12:amd64 (3.18.2-1ubuntu1, automatic), libclone-perl:amd64 (0.38-1build1, automatic), geoclue:amd64 (0.12.99-4ubuntu1, automatic), libgee-0.8-2:amd64 (0.18.0-1, automatic), libsub-name-perl:amd64 (0.14-1build1, automatic), libebook-1.2-16:amd64 (3.18.5-1ubuntu1.1, automatic), gir1.2-gnomekeyring-1.0:amd64 (3.12.0-1build1, automatic), yelp-xsl:amd64 (3.18.1-1, automatic), im-config:amd64 (0.29-1ubuntu12.4, automatic), pkg-config:amd64 (0.29.1-0ubuntu1, automatic), libiec61883-0:amd64 (1.2.0-0.2, automatic), system-config-printer-gnome:amd64 (1.5.7+20160212-0ubuntu2, automatic), libtag1v5:amd64 (1.9.1-2.4ubuntu1, automatic), hwdata:amd64 (0.267-1, automatic), indicator-bluetooth:amd64 (0.0.6+16.04.20160526-0ubuntu1, automatic), libqt5webkit5:amd64 (5.5.1+dfsg-2ubuntu1, automatic), lintian:amd64 (2.5.43ubuntu0.1, automatic), unity-control-center-signon:amd64 (0.1.8+16.04.20160201-0ubuntu1, automatic), libmm-glib0:amd64 (1.6.4-1ubuntu0.16.04.1, automatic), system-config-printer-udev:amd64 (1.5.7+20160212-0ubuntu2, automatic), libnma0:amd64 (1.2.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.4, automatic), gstreamer1.0-x:amd64 (1.8.3-1ubuntu0.2, automatic), libyaml-libyaml-perl:amd64 (0.41-6build1, automatic), libcanberra-pulse:amd64 (0.30-2.1ubuntu1, automatic), indicator-datetime:amd64 (15.10+16.04.20160406-0ubuntu1, automatic), libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37:amd64 (2.20.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, automatic), libnma-common:amd64 (1.2.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.4, automatic), libmbim-proxy:amd64 (1.14.0-1ubuntu0.16.04.1, automatic), wpasupplicant:amd64 (2.4-0ubuntu6.2, automatic), libgeoclue0:amd64 (0.12.99-4ubuntu1, automatic), usb-modeswitch-data:amd64 (20151101-1, automatic), libio-string-perl:amd64 (1.08-3, automatic), libio-pty-perl:amd64 (1:1.08-1.1build1, automatic), libsmbclient:amd64 (2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.13, automatic), libgnome-menu-3-0:amd64 (3.13.3-6ubuntu3.1, automatic), libaccounts-glib0:amd64 (1.21+16.04.20160222-0ubuntu1, automatic), gnome-screensaver:amd64 (3.6.1-7ubuntu4, automatic), gnome-session-bin:amd64 (3.18.1.2-1ubuntu1.16.04.2, automatic), libnm-gtk0:amd64 (1.2.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.4, automatic), libcheese-gtk25:amd64 (3.18.1-2ubuntu3, automatic), screen-resolution-extra:amd64 (0.17.1.1~16.04.1, automatic), cheese-common:amd64 (3.18.1-2ubuntu3, automatic), bluez-obexd:amd64 (5.37-0ubuntu5.1, automatic), python3-aptdaemon.pkcompat:amd64 (1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu14, automatic), libsocket6-perl:amd64 (0.25-1build2, automatic), libqt5opengl5:amd64 (5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.5, automatic), ibus:amd64 (1.5.11-1ubuntu2.1, automatic), libpwquality1:amd64 (1.3.0-0ubuntu1, automatic), python3-cairo:amd64 (1.10.0+dfsg-5build1, automatic), python3-aptdaemon:amd64 (1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu14, automatic), libunity-control-center1:amd64 (15.04.0+16.04.20171130-0ubuntu1, automatic), hardening-includes:amd64 (2.7ubuntu2, automatic), upstart:amd64 (1.13.2-0ubuntu21.1, automatic), libdigest-hmac-perl:amd64 (1.03+dfsg-1, automatic), libfcitx-utils0:amd64 (1:4.2.9.1-1ubuntu1.16.04.2, automatic), libdata-alias-perl:amd64 (1.20-1build1, automatic), gir1.2-packagekitglib-1.0:amd64 (0.8.17-4ubuntu6~gcc5.4ubuntu1.3, automatic), libnet-domain-tld-perl:amd64 (1.73-1, automatic), libebook-contacts-1.2-2:amd64 (3.18.5-1ubuntu1.1, automatic), indicator-application:amd64 (12.10.1+16.04.20170120-0ubuntu1, automatic), libibus-1.0-5:amd64 (1.5.11-1ubuntu2.1, automatic), libsignon-glib1:amd64 (1.13+16.04.20151209.1-0ubuntu1, automatic), libedata-book-1.2-25:amd64 (3.18.5-1ubuntu1.1, automatic), libido3-0.1-0:amd64 (13.10.0+16.04.20161028-0ubuntu1, automatic), gir1.2-ibus-1.0:amd64 (1.5.11-1ubuntu2.1, automatic), unity-settings-daemon:amd64 (15.04.1+16.04.20160701-0ubuntu1, automatic), libcheese8:amd64 (3.18.1-2ubuntu3, automatic), modemmanager:amd64 (1.6.4-1ubuntu0.16.04.1, automatic), gnome-user-share:amd64 (3.14.2-2ubuntu4, automatic), nautilus-data:amd64 (1:3.18.4.is.3.14.3-0ubuntu6, automatic), libedata-cal-1.2-28:amd64 (3.18.5-1ubuntu1.1, automatic), avahi-utils:amd64 (0.6.32~rc+dfsg-1ubuntu2.2, automatic), libtimezonemap-data:amd64 (0.4.5, automatic), signon-ui-service:amd64 (0.17+16.04.20151125-0ubuntu1, automatic), usb-modeswitch:amd64 (2.2.5+repack0-1ubuntu1, automatic), mesa-vdpau-drivers:amd64 (18.0.5-0ubuntu0~16.04.1, automatic), aptdaemon:amd64 (1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu14, automatic), ocl-icd-libopencl1:amd64 (2.2.8-1, automatic), signon-keyring-extension:amd64 (0.6+14.10.20140513-0ubuntu2, automatic), libv4l-0:amd64 (1.10.0-1, automatic), libgnomekbd8:amd64 (3.6.0-1ubuntu2, automatic), libv4lconvert0:amd64 (1.10.0-1, automatic), system-config-printer-common:amd64 (1.5.7+20160212-0ubuntu2, automatic), libjansson4:amd64 (2.7-3ubuntu0.1, automatic), gstreamer1.0-clutter-3.0:amd64 (3.0.18-1, automatic), libtag1v5-vanilla:amd64 (1.9.1-2.4ubuntu1, automatic), libaccount-plugin-google:amd64 (0.12+16.04.20160126-0ubuntu1, automatic), libcamel-1.2-54:amd64 (3.18.5-1ubuntu1.1, automatic), libecal-1.2-19:amd64 (3.18.5-1ubuntu1.1, automatic), libipc-run-perl:amd64 (0.94-1, automatic), pinentry-gnome3:amd64 (0.9.7-3, automatic), python3-lxml:amd64 (3.5.0-1build1, automatic), libavc1394-0:amd64 (0.5.4-4, automatic), libgnomekbd-common:amd64 (3.6.0-1ubuntu2, automatic), libclutter-1.0-common:amd64 (1.24.2-1, automatic), indicator-applet:amd64 (12.10.2+15.04.20141127.2-0ubuntu1, automatic), indicator-power:amd64 (12.10.6+16.04.20160105-0ubuntu1, automatic), libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18:amd64 (2.20.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, automatic), dconf-cli:amd64 (0.24.0-2, automatic), bbswitch-dkms:amd64 (0.8-3ubuntu1, automatic), libmbim-glib4:amd64 (1.14.0-1ubuntu0.16.04.1, automatic), libclass-accessor-perl:amd64 (0.34-1, automatic), libgeonames0:amd64 (0.2+16.04.20160321-0ubuntu1, automatic), libqt5quick5:amd64 (5.5.1-2ubuntu6, automatic), libedataserver-1.2-21:amd64 (3.18.5-1ubuntu1.1, automatic), nvidia-opencl-icd-384:amd64 (384.130-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, automatic), libmtp-common:amd64 (1.1.10-2ubuntu1, automatic), signon-ui:amd64 (0.17+16.04.20151125-0ubuntu1, automatic), lightdm:amd64 (1.18.3-0ubuntu1.1, automatic), libsignon-extension1:amd64 (8.58+16.04.20151106-0ubuntu1, automatic), libgweather-common:amd64 (3.18.2-0ubuntu0.2, automatic), libnet-ip-perl:amd64 (1.26-1, automatic), nvidia-384:amd64 (384.130-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), evolution-data-server-online-accounts:amd64 (3.18.5-1ubuntu1.1, automatic), signon-ui-x11:amd64 (0.17+16.04.20151125-0ubuntu1, automatic), liblightdm-gobject-1-0:amd64 (1.18.3-0ubuntu1.1, automatic), libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37-gtk2:amd64 (2.20.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, automatic), indicator-messages:amd64 (13.10.1+15.10.20150505-0ubuntu1, automatic), libgtop-2.0-10:amd64 (2.32.0-1, automatic), ippusbxd:amd64 (1.23-1, automatic), diffstat:amd64 (1.61-1, automatic), liburl-dispatcher1:amd64 (0.1+16.04.20151110-0ubuntu2, automatic), libclutter-gtk-1.0-0:amd64 (1.6.6-1, automatic), nvidia-settings:amd64 (361.42-0ubuntu1, automatic), python3-bs4:amd64 (4.4.1-1, automatic), libpanel-applet0:amd64 (1:3.18.3-0ubuntu0.1, automatic), gnome-menus:amd64 (3.13.3-6ubuntu3.1, automatic)
```

Comment: What do the last lines of `/var/log/apt/history.log` say?

Comment: I have updated the question with the log entry from this install attempt.

Comment: OK after "Install" it lists all 256 packages it was going to install. I don't think any have been actually installed; just downloaded and unpacked. Try to remove one of them, say `sudo apt remove libunity-settings-daemon1`. You may be asked to remove the `apt lock` first.

Comment: I can't run apt anymore: 'E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.' Not sure if I can do the suggested command without actually installing all that bloat.

Comment: Neither am I, but other than just trying I'm out of options here. In any case you could simply remove the 256 packages afterwards.

Comment: I ran `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and it apparently only configured the packages that were unpacked before the keyboard interrupt. Then I was able to `apt-get purge` all these packages except the last: `dpkg: error processing package libqt5opengl5:amd64 (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration`
This could be fixed via: 'sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq libqt5opengl5'. Will request an edit on ubuntuuser's WiKi for sure!

Comment: Updates to the original problem should be edited into the original question, clearly labelled. Comments are not intended for followup, can be deleted, and may not be fully read by some contributors.

Comment: The original post can't be extended due to max char restrictions.